# LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} in cls file

Tags: fonts

The error message:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexmf SimSun
! I can't find file `SimSun'.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input SimSun
                                                  
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input SimSun
                                                  
Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: SimSun.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input SimSun' failed to make SimSun.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.


./thuthesis.cls:687: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.687     }
           
No pages of output.
```

Source code about the error(.cls l.687):

```latex
\newcommand\thu@mac@word@font@path{%
  /Applications/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/Resources/DFonts/%
}
\ifthu@fontset@auto
  \ifthu@system@windows
    \thusetup{fontset = windows}
  \else
    \IfFontExistsTF{SimSun}{
      \thusetup{fontset = windows}
    }{
      \IfFileExists{\thu@mac@word@font@path/SimSun.ttf}{
        \thusetup{fontset = windows}
      }{
        \ifthu@system@mac
          \thusetup{fontset = mac}
        \else
          \IfFontExistsTF{Noto Serif CJK SC}{
            \thusetup{fontset = ubuntu}
          }{
            \thusetup{fontset = fandol}
          }
        \fi
      }
    } % l.687
  \fi
\fi
```

I have not learnt tex yet. But this piece of code in cls file which I use tells that, if it finds SimSun.ttf, fontset will be windows.

I'm not sure whether the error has something to do with `I can't find file SimSun.`. The platform is mac. But SimSun.ttf does exists, its path is `/Applications/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/Resources/DFonts/SimSun.ttf`.

As for fontspec, code in thuthesis.cls:

```latex
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
```

I think the error has nothing to do with the tex file. Its content:

```latex
\documentclass[degree=master]{thuthesis}

\input{thusetup}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\input{data/committee}

\copyrightpage

\frontmatter
\input{data/abstract}

\tableofcontents


\input{data/denotation}


\mainmatter
\input{data/chap01}
\input{data/chap02}
\input{data/chap03}
\input{data/chap04}

\backmatter

\appendix
\input{data/appendix}

\input{data/acknowledgements}

\statement

\input{data/resume}

\input{data/comments}

\input{data/resolution}

\end{document}
```

I compile with xelatex. The distribution version is

```
XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2018)
kpathsea version 6.3.0
```

Comment: You should provide you `tex` file code as well (probably a MWE). Do you use `xelatex` and `fontspec` package and try to change the font to simsun?

Comment: I think somehow the simsun not installed on your system. Could you try `\documentclass[degree=master,fontset=none]{thuthesis}` to see if it can compile?

Comment: There are two `/` when it gets to SimSun: one in `\thu@mac@word@font@path` + `/SimSun.ttf`. Have you contacted the document class maintainer? In the meantine, also try `fontset=mac` or `fontset=fandol`.